# Android smack 4.1 issue with connection

Tags: java, android, smack, google-talk

I'm trying to make a connection with `GoogleTalk` in android using `Smack`.
I've followed numerous tutorials examples on the internet yet still I can't seem to make it work.

```
public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";

public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";
public static final String USERNAME = "myemail@gmail.com";
public static final String PASSWORD = "mypassword";
```

My above credentials are correct...

```
 XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
   connConfig.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
   connConfig.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
   connConfig.setServiceName(SERVICE);
   connConfig.setHost(HOST);
   connConfig.setPort(PORT);
   connConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
   //setCompressionEnabled(false).build();
   //(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
   XMPPTCPConnection connection = new  XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig.build());
     try {
       connection.connect();
       Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+connection.getHost());
     } catch (XMPPException ex) {
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
         setConnection(null);
     }
     catch(SmackException ex){
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
         setConnection(null);
     }
     catch(IOException ex){
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
         setConnection(null);
     }
```

I get `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializeError`

on this line

`XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder connConfig = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();` //line 184

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-120
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.example.samsungchatexample.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:184)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.getVersion(SmackConfiguration.java:96)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<clinit>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:38)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.loadSmackClass(SmackInitialization.java:213)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.parseClassesToLoad(SmackInitialization.java:193)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:163)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:148)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:116)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.javax.JavaxResolver.<clinit>(JavaxResolver.java:50)
```

Can someone please help me with this ? I've tested this on `KitKat` and `JellyBean`
Same exception on both so this is not a glitch with context to OS versions. What am I missing ?

Comment: did u fixed the issue ? myself getting the same error

Comment: Change user name from myemail@gmail.com to myemail.

Comment: @anshad it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I do face problem  while establishing a connection using SMACK 4.1.
When I included all of these libraries mentioned below then I successfully established a connection. Give it a try :) Hope you succeed.

1. jxmpp-core-0.4.1
2. jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.1
3. minidns-0.1.1
4. smack-android-4.1.0.jar
5. smack-android-extensions-4.1.0
6. smack-core-4.1.0
7. smack-extensions-4.1.0
8. smack-im-4.1.0
9. smack-tcp-4.1.0

Comment: can you post your source code for the connection ? and did you achieve above in android ??

Comment: @Sharp edge.... Yes I'm able to establish a connection with the server and successfully logged in...  :)
This is the link of my question in which i have posted my source code and  you can get it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755230/smack-4-1-sasl-authentication-error/29769292#29769292