# Smack 4.1 SASL authentication error

Tags: android, eclipse, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack 4.1 native library for android to develop a chat application. I'm able to set a connection between my application and my server but I'm getting SmackException regarding SASL authentication while logging in.

**Points to be noted.**

1. There is no SASL authentication required on my server side.
2. My application is not crashing but getting the following errors which i have shown below in my log cat snnippet.

I'm using eclipse Luna and JDK version 1.7 and I have included the following libraries in the libs folder.

1. jxmpp-core-0.4.1
2. jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.1
3. minidns-0.1.1
4. smack-android-4.1.0.jar
5. smack-android-extensions-4.1.0
6. smack-core-4.1.0
7. smack-extensions-4.1.0
8. smack-im-4.1.0
9. smack-tcp-4.1.0

This is my code which I'm using to establish a connection.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, pass);
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setResource("testServices");
        configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
        configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
        configBuilder.setHost(DOMAIN);
        configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(
                configBuilder.build());

        /** Connecting to the server */
        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /** LogingIn to the server */
        try {

            //SASLMechanism.PLAIN();
            //SASLAuthentication.("PLAIN", 0);

            connection.login(userName, pass);
            // connection.login();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /** LogingOut from the server */
        connection.disconnect();
```

This is my logcat output.

```
04-20 22:22:51.584: D/SMACK(8335): SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='my_server_url' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='10001@my_server_url' xml:lang='en'>
04-20 22:22:52.519: D/SMACK(8335): RECV (0): <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" version="1.0" id="0768491716592086" from="my_server_url">
04-20 22:22:53.744: D/SMACK(8335): RECV (0): <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
04-20 22:22:53.749: I/(8335): Connected to "smy_server_url"

04-21 12:24:55.815: I/(16566): SmackException to my_server_link.comorg.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: SASL Authentication failed. No known authentication mechanisims.
04-20 22:22:53.754: W/System.err(8335): org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: SASL Authentication failed. No known authentication mechanisims.
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:254)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnection.java:365)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:452)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:427)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at com.epixoft.ui.LoginActivity$ConnectionTestTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:120)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at com.epixoft.ui.LoginActivity$ConnectionTestTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-20 22:22:53.759: W/System.err(8335):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-20 22:22:53.764: W/System.err(8335):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-20 22:22:53.764: W/System.err(8335):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-20 22:22:53.764: W/System.err(8335):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-20 22:22:53.784: D/SMACK(8335): SENT (0): <presence id='PwoLk-3' type='unavailable'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>
04-20 22:22:53.789: D/SMACK(8335): SENT (0): </stream:stream>
04-20 22:22:53.864: E/ViewRootImpl(8335): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
cheers :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After struggling a lot finally i have found the solution to my problem.

I have to import the `smack-sasl-provided-4.1.0.jar` to get rid of this SASLAuthentication error.

Comment: Can you describe your answer more ? @Taimur Khan