# GCM XMPP Server using Smack 4.1.0 - which jars need to be added

Tags: xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I'm trying to adapt the example provided [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) for Smack 4.1.0. and getting error like:
PacketInterceptor, DefaultPacketExtension, PacketExtensionProvider classes are missing in smack library.
PacketListener, PacketTypeFilter, Packet, PacketExtension classes are depricated.
Am I doing something incorrect.
Am I missing something? Please note I am using JDK 7.
If anyone can explain which smack JARS need to be included, will be really great.

Answer (score 1):

To use Smack 4.1 in your project, you need to include the following jars

1. jxmpp-core-0.4.1
2. jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.1
3. minidns-0.1.1
4. smack-android-4.1.0.jar
5. smack-android-extensions-4.1.0
6. smack-core-4.1.0
7. smack-extensions-4.1.0
8. smack-im-4.1.0
9. smack-tcp-4.1.0

as mentioned here : [Android smack 4.1 issue with connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727997/android-smack-4-1-issue-with-connection)